# Human speakable password generator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random, password-generator

I am in the process of developing a script that generates human-speakable strings for use in passwords. I am only concerned with English-sounding phrases. So far I have come up with the notion of different arrays:

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
single_consonants = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'];
double_consonants_leading = ['Bh','Bl','Br','By','Ch','Cl','Cr','Cy','Dr','Dw','Dy','Fl','Fr','Fy','Gh','Gl','Gn','Gr','Gw','Gy','Hy','Jy','Kn','Kr','Kw','Ky','Ly','Mc','Mn','Mr','My','Ny','Ph','Pl','Pn','Pr','Ps','Py','Q','Rh','Ry','Sc','Sh','Sk','Sl','Sm','Sn','Sp','St','Sv','Sw','Sy','Th','Tr','Ts','Tw','Ty','Vr','Vy','Wh','Wr','Wy','Xy','Y','Z'];
double_consonants_trailing = [...'ch'...];
tripple_consonants_leading = [...'Dry','Fly'...];
tripple_consonants_trailing = [...'rch'...];
```

I will then define a set of *rules* to concatenate elements from these arrays to create strings but not necessarily words that you would find in the dictionary.

An example is: "**Frug-Spunner-Snow-Drive**"

Another alternative is to use a list of words found in the dictionary, however, my first thought on that is that it is a finite list. As soon as someone knows which list you are generating strings from it will inevitably reduce the time taken to crack it.

My solution will not only create words found in the dictionary but strings that sound like words.

```
function generateString(length)
{
.
.
.
return randomString;
}

generateString(7);
```

**outputs:** "Brownen" (a random string)

The function will take an argument *length* and return a string of that length, it could be improved by accepting more arguments such as how many *parts* to use and the *separator* to be used between those *parts*.

```
function generateString(parts,lengthOfPart,separator)
{
.
.
.
return randomString;
}

generateString(4,5,"-");
```

**outputs:** "Crown-Drive-Knife-Gnome" (4 strings, each 5 characters long split by a hypen)

This is what I have so far, and the question itself is a work in progress. I would like to make sure that I am on the right track.

**My question is:**
Is this overkill? What are the pros and cons? And ultimately, how will I go about developing this in JavaScript?

**Edit 1 (13/11/2013)**

I have since found an article here: http://www.baekdal.com/insights/password-security-usability that describes using a list of common words, but as long as three+ words are used at any given time then it is very secure as the time it takes to break it is so long the thing you are trying to protect will be of little value.

**Edit 2 (10:10 14/11/2013)**

I have found another article referring to Markov Chain generator http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2013/02/draft-title-generator-using-markov-chains in Javascript, but again the text is generated from a *source text*. Is this possible without it and by defining rules.

Comment: http://preshing.com/20110811/xkcd-password-generator/

Comment: Different languages have different rules for what's pronounceable. English speakers have a very hard time with "*Eyjafjallajokull*", but that's perfectly fine in Icelandic. In principal, almost any sequence of letters could be pronounceable in some language.

Comment: I didn't define it in the question (I will now) but I am just referring to English-sounding phrases.

Comment: @Diodeus, Jeff Preshing who wrote that script uses only 1949 words, and although there are 4 words used at a time the list is somewhat limited.

Comment: I would just generate passphrases based on a word list of about 10,000 words. Safe, easy to remember, and not difficult to implement. The only caveat is typing time.

Comment: @minty thank you, I think that clarifies my question, and upon further reading here - http://www.baekdal.com/insights/password-security-usability it is feasible to use a common dictionary of words.

Comment: @rninty that's not safe at all.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Care to expand? If you’re talking about the random number generator, I didn’t specify which one, nor whether it was client-side or server-side.

Comment: I think Benjamin is right, you're limiting the entropy because your word list or your rules are limited (e.g. "just something english people can pronounce") and all the passwords are just permutations of that list. That seems to be very insecure.

Comment: @ultima_rat0: All passwords are also just several repetitions of the bits 1 and 0. The entropy is “limited”, but it’s still high if you make it long enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good approach might be to use a Markov Chain that is generated from a large body of English text. A Markov Chain is basically a probabilistic construct which is dependent upon the source from which it is generated, so you are likely to get many English-like words that are pronounceable. In a Markov Chain, you have a state from which you can transition into many other states based on a probability. Since your Markov Chain will be based on English letters from a body of English text, transitions from one letter to another letter will be more probable than a transition to a different one. For example, it is more likely to transition from `c` to `a` or `o`, than from `c` to `z` or `x`. I have a [simple Perl script](https://github.com/vivin/sulekha) that generates Markov Chains based on words or letters and I was able to get the following "words" that seem to be pretty pronounceable:

```
Engulary 
Beavy 
Lan 
Irstatinval
Bassions
Assish 
Forld  
Anturopean 
Cought 
Froot 
Thation
```

Keep in mind though that the entropy is limited by the source material, so it is better to have a large body that you're generating words from. Taking a pointer from the [xkcd password generator](http://preshing.com/20110811/xkcd-password-generator/) mentioned by [Diodeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12579/diodeus), you can combine two or more of these words into pronounceable but nonsensical phrase, that can be a password as well.

Comment: Thanks @Vivin but is this a) possible in Javascript and b) possible without having a base text, just with the kind of rules/arrays I set above?

Comment: @Mike Yes, this is possible in JavaScript. You could also do it without the base text if you generate the frequency table beforehand and just use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple** example without words list (only letters defined) for people with **very good memory** ... To get human speakable words, more rules should be added like 4 vowels together. Results

```
Diecrue - Okeiae - Auasvei
Aovaua - Biaeeo - Suwien
Aiasmea - Aueglou - Koiroa
Doiiui - Domeab - Slokaoa
Oeiuju - Yootraa - Koaeua
Qagwisva - Hiexau - Yovaca
Fleeaee - Peaoui - Xafriaa
Vaaute - Iqovai - Naaaesn
Yauehe - Ueeguu - Mrouiepr
Smikreua - Friusnut - Aoqiji
```

main code: http://jsfiddle.net/mMZ3Y/

```
function get_password_word(n){
    var data1 = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
    var data2 = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'];
    var data3 = ['bl','br','cl','cr','dr','dw','fl','fr','gl','gr','gw','kn','kr','kw','mr','ph','pl','pn','pr','ps','sc','sh','sk','sl','sm','sn','sp','st','sv','sw','tr','ts','wh'];

    var str = '';
    var last = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        var type = getRandomInt(1, 10);
        //avoiding some cases
        if(last == 3)
            type = 1;
        if(last == 2)
            type = 1;
        if(last == 1 && getRandomInt(1, 2) == 1)
            type = 2;
        //generate
        if(type < 4){ //40%
            str += data1[getRandomInt(0, data1.length-1)];
            last = 1;
            }
        else if(type < 9){  //40%
            str += data2[getRandomInt(0, data2.length-1)];
            last = 2;
            }
        else{ //20%
            str += data3[getRandomInt(0, data3.length-1)];
            last = 3;
            }
        }
    str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
    return str;
    }
```

Comment: That's great, could you explain what the last and type does? Also, where did you get the weightings from for the percentages? Would I simply need to add more data arrays (for leading triples, trailing triples etc?)

Comment: last stores last created char type. 1 - vowel, 2 - 1 consonant, 3 - 2 consonants together. Percentages comes from random number between 1 and 10  - "var type = getRandomInt(1, 10);"